# Simple MongoDB JSON structure

Tags: json, mongodb

I am doing a tutorial and having some trouble understanding the semantics of the task.

It basically says (directly translated)

> Write a command that adds a new document with the "General" category, today's date, and, under "content", a "header" that reads "MongoDB commands programmed by" and then your name under "content".

What confuses me is the whole "a header that reads "MongoDB commands..." since that would make me have to nest the name + header into the "content".

The next step hints that this should not be done.

> A search that displays the contents of the document above, formatted  .pretty (). The condition in the search must contain your name as a value for "Content"

So this indicates that the search would be db.database.find({"name": "My Name"}), thus the header nested is not really possible.

This is how I tried to structure the JSON, but then the search won't work.

```
{
    "general" : [
      "date" : new Date(), 
      "content" : [
         "header" : "MongoDB commands programmed by",
         "name" : "John Doe"
      ]
    ]
}
```

Am I thinking about it in the wrong way? It's a beginner tutorial so it should not be extensively hard, but there is now answer sheet unfortunately that's why I am making this thread after googling a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I'll do something like that:

```
{
  "category": "general",
  "date" : new Date(), 
  "content" : {
     "header" : "MongoDB commands programmed by",
     "name" : "John Doe"
  }
}
```